# Predict Command with GAM package in R

Tags: r, predict, gam

I am trying to use the predict command for gam functions in the "gam" package.  I find that when I have two or more splines that I cannot predict onto a new sample, even if the new sample is the original data or a subset of the original data.  The last two lines in the code below gives an error.

EDIT: gam.data is a dataset that comes with the gam package and used in the examples for gam and predict.gam.  It's a data.frame with columns: x, y, z, f, probf, ybin, and ybin 2 -- all numeric. –

```
require(gam)

data(gam.data)
Gam.object <- gam(y ~ s(x,z,df=6)+s(f,probf,df=6),data=gam.data)
summary(Gam.object)
predict(Gam.object)
predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data)
predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data[1:20,])
```

predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data)

> Error in gam.s(data[["s(f, probf, df = 6)"]], z, w, spar = probf, df = 6,  : 
>     object 'probf' not found

predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data[1:20,])

> Error in gam.s(data[["s(f, probf, df = 6)"]], z, w, spar = probf, df = 6,  : 
>     object 'probf' not found

Comment: Not enough information provided. Use [edit] to post much greater detail about the `gam.data` object. Review the help pages and note that the spar parameter to is supposed to be a single value.

Comment: @42- `gam.data` is built in to the `gam` library. It's a data.frame with columns: x, y, z, f, probf, ybin, and ybin 2 -- all numeric.

Comment: you could create two new variables in your data and fit the model with those two variables and it works

Comment: @rawr Can you show me how?

Comment: `gam.data <- within(gam.data, {x1 <- s(x,z,df=6); x2 <- s(f,probf,df=6)}); Gam.object <- gam(y ~ x1 + x2, data=gam.data)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be missing a call to terms="response" (or some other terms call) in the predict command.

The following runs:

```
data(gam.data)
Gam.object <- gam(y ~ s(x,z,df=6)+s(f,probf,df=6),data=gam.data)
summary(Gam.object)
predict(Gam.object)
predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data,terms="response")
predict(Gam.object,newdata=gam.data[1:20,],terms="response")
```

Comment: These values are different that his first `predict()` output.  The points don't fall all on the diagonal: `plot(predict(Gam.object), predict(Gam.object,terms = "response", newdata=gam.data))`

Comment: That is weird.  I'm not sure why.  I tried terms="link", which should be the default, but that did not work.

Comment: terms=NULL seems to give the same result as terms="response"